# when I call drawRect:, UIView class properties seemingly disappear

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I am having some serious issues trying to figure out why this problem is happening: 
[UIView class properties seemingly disappear when I call drawRect:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095594/uiview-class-properties-seemingly-disappear-when-i-call-drawrect)

Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIView class properties seemingly disappear when I call drawRect:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095594/uiview-class-properties-seemingly-disappear-when-i-call-drawrect)

Comment: Asking the same question again isn't going to help get an answer. That's called a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates). Try editing / revising your original question. Doing so will [bump it to the front page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7054/235574).